# Scaling an iframe on window resize

Tags: css, iframe, webkit-transform

I'm trying to scale an iframe based on the window size.
Coming through the iframe is a html5 game at 1600px x 900px

I have used the script below to scale the game, so I know that much can be done. While the code below renders the game into a small box, is there any way I can have it scale to fit the window, while maintaining the 16:9 aspect ratio?

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">

    .tab{
       position:relative;
       width:265px;170px;
    }
    .tab iframe{
        position:relative;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.3, 0.29);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.3, 0.29);
        transform: scale(0.3, 0.29);
        -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
        transform-origin:0 0;
        position:relative;
        z-index:90;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="tab0" class="tab">
        <iframe src="game.html" width="1600" height="900" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>

</body>
```

For reference I am a game artist and have only used code(javascript/css/html) for quest dialogues and other smaller game features. I'm currently the last one working on the project and it was requested this feature be implemented to the game.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it like this, using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe').attr('width',$(window).width());
    $('iframe').attr('height',($('iframe').attr('width') * (9/16)));
})
```

Note: this doesn't make the iframe 1600 pixels wide, it simply makes it the full width, and makes the height = to the width multiplied by 9/16 ie: maintains a 16:9 aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot scale to window height and width at every time and keep an ratio of 16:9, that is mathematical not possible.
If you want to keep a ratio of 16:9 constant you can take the window width, or the height and then scale the opposite site to the right value to keep your ratio.

I.E. your window get resized to 800px width and 600px height and you want to keep the width of the window in full then you must scale the height of your box to 450px to keep a ratio of 16:9.

Comment: thanks for your input. i plan to base it on the windows width. To be clearer in my question, is it possible to keep the game/iframe resolution at 1600px x 900px, no matter what size the window currently is - using transform-scale?

Comment: @Sonnyjim Actually you have to take both the width and the height into consideration. If in Sven's example, the window height is less than 450 pixels, you should take that as the iframe height and calculate the width from it.

Comment: You could do that very easy if you use jQuery. Then you have the resize() function. On load and on every resize of the Window you must then figure out the new width. The formula for the height would be (box-width*9/16). And the box you set to a width of 100% to have at every time full window width.

Comment: @Sonnyjim And your other question, no, it is not really possible to influence the content of an iframe from the window. You should do that in the content itself.

Comment: @ Mr Lister - Very good comment I haven't thought about that. If you want to prevent scrolling you must then make the math for the ratio based on the width. If the new height would be bigger than the existing height you make the math for the ratio based on the height and set then new height and width for the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="game.html" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```